# Connecting meteorjs app to atlas mongodb having error could not locate valid servers

Tags: meteor, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect my Meteor application to Atlas MongoDB, 
I am setting `MONGO_URL` and `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` as follows:

`MONGO_URL="mongodb://username:password@host:27017,host:27017,host:27017/databasename?ssl=true&replicaSet=melee-shard-0&authSource=admin"`

`MONGO_OPLOG_URL="mongodb://username:password@host:27017,host:27017,host:27017/local?ssl=true&replicaSet=melee-shard-0&authSource=admin"`

But, I am getting error while starting the Meteor app:

> Error: Could not locate any valid servers in initial seed list

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try to use just one server, for the sake of debugging?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried with one server as well, like below, `mongodb://username:password@host:27017/database?ssl=true&authSource=admin` If the host is secondary server then it shows mongo error `not master, slave ok`, If host is primary server then it didn't connect just stops, Not starting the app if specifying only primary.

Comment: It would be hard to help you without seeing your replica configuration

Comment: @Styx replica configuration is correct, I am able to connect to cluster using mongo shell and other GUI tools like studio3t. Is there any issue with ssl=true, or nodejs driver?

Comment: I have a working  connection with using "mongodb+srv".   export MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://some_usr:some_pswd@some_cluster/meteor?retryWrites=true&w=majority